# Slim don't escape markdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I have a slim view like this:

```
.post
    h1
        = title(@post.title)
        small = published_at(@post) unless @post.draft?
    hr

    markdown:
        #{{ @post.content }}
```

The problem is `@post.content` (which is in markdown) keeps being escaped (so instead of `h1` being rendered I see a `#` on the screen etc).
According to the [slim documentation](http://rdoc.info/gems/slim/file/README.md#Text_interpolation), the `{{ }}` should result in unescaped content, except it is not working.

How do I get my markdown to not be escaped?

Comment: i don't think the markdown filter works that way. if you want the post-content to be markdown use a gem like redcarpet

Comment: Thats what I did, although this worked in Haml